No module named ‘_bpy’ when using python multiprocessing?
Is there any solution for the problem which was described on the development forum:
No module named ‘_bpy’ when using python multiprocessing?
I'm trying to use multiprocessing to join meshes but I get the bpy import error.
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   results = executor.map(join_op, index_list)

Error message:
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap    self.run()
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 122, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\My_Addon\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import bpy
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from _bpy import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\My_Addon\operators.py", line 518, in execute
    for result in results:
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 575, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 621, in result_iterator
    yield _result_or_cancel(fs.pop())
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 319, in _result_or_cancel
    return fut.result(timeout)
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 451, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

I don't understand the workaround posted as last entry in the mentioned link.
Is there a guide or better information for using multiple processes in Blender?
(I tested it on 4.1 as well but I get the same error.)
EDIT:
Here is a little dummy script that shows the problem (can be run from Blender script editor):
from multiprocessing import current_process
if current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
    import bpy
import concurrent.futures

print('Here we go... \n\n\n')

index = [1,2]
first_mesh = []
second_mesh = []

NewCollection = bpy.data.collections.new("Test")
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(NewCollection)
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[NewCollection.name]

for x in range(4):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=0.5, enter_editmode=False, align='CURSOR', location=(x, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.context.active_object.name = "first_" +  str(x)
    first_mesh.append(bpy.context.active_object)
    
for x in range(4):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=0.5, enter_editmode=False, align='CURSOR', location=(x, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.context.active_object.name = "second_" +  str(x)
    second_mesh.append(bpy.context.active_object)
    
def join_op(i):
    override = {}
    if i == 1:
        override["active_object"] = first_mesh[1]
        override["selected_editable_objects"] = first_mesh
        with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
            bpy.ops.object.join()
    if i == 2:
        override["active_object"] = second_mesh[1]
        override["selected_editable_objects"] = second_mesh
        with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
            bpy.ops.object.join()        
        
# Multi Processing Version    
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(join_op, index)

# Non Multi processing version 
#for x in index:
#    join_op(x)

You can comment out either the multi processing version or the normal version. Running the non multi version nicely joins the meshes as intended.
Running the multi processing version, doesn't joins the meshes and gives the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\runpy.py", line 288, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\_BLENDER\blender-3.6.8-windows-x64\3.6\python\lib\runpy.py", line 252, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(decoded_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\WORK\\TEST_MultiProcess_Import_BPY.blend\\Text'

The error message is a bit different, because it is run from the Blender script window and not as an Add-On but at the end it tries to refer to some path f: and looking for some Text.
I guess it's the same problem, that for spawning a new process it needs some BPY components which it can't find.
It would be great if someone would have a working solution or workaround.  (For an Add-On, not for the script window .

Well, there is no module named "_bpy", it's "bpy", without the "_".

Could you post the full code that would reproduce the issue?

Yeah, but why does it try to import _bpy? I'm importin bpy right at the beginning of my script. I'm not trying to import _bpy anywhere. That is coming from the multiprocessing module. The rest of the code is very large. The join_op I'm calling works fine when called without multiprocessing.

I mean sure, there might be someone here who just knows, without looking into it, but what are the chances? You should provide some example code that one can just copy/paste and run to reproduce the issue - I think that always increases the chances of getting help. It's best if that can be the full actual code you run, but at least a stripped down version that only reproduces the issue might also be helpful.

"Is there a guide or better information for using multiple processes in Blender?" I don't think you can use multiple processes in Blender and I think that's the issue. You can use bpy from a single process inside Blender and if you need to speed up some complex calculations, you can do that in Python separately. The post in your link explains, how to separate bpy stuff from multiprocessing the way I understand it.

I added a little example that can be run from the script window. It produces a different error message but I guess the problem is the same. (Spawning processes with their own python interpreters including BPY.)

Yes, well, bpy is only an API that accesses Blender, so you cannot make it multi process because it's for accessing Blender's functionality, that is one process - Blender. So this is not supposed to work. I mean as far as I understand at least.

Have you read this section of the bpy scripting Gotchas page?

Threading is more problematic than multiprocessing as I understand.

Joining meshes would be perfect for multiprocessing as the data is unique (if the mesh list is done properly). In the link of the link of my post is a big discussion about the path problematic regarding python and Blender python. I was hoping that in the meantime someone came up with a solution for those problems.

You can do that, but you would need to do that in Python without bpy and you would need to move data back and forth and also Python is generally way slower for stuff like that than languages like C++, so what you have in Blender. It's not a very good idea probably. Also joining meshes seems to be multi-threaded in Blender anyway from my very quick rough test just seeing CPU core utilization in Task Manager.

I just tested my non Multiprocessing version on a large dataset and from the 8 cores of my machine, only one was utilized by the join operation. (14% CPU)
